# How to find a support vector machine by hand with only a few data points?

Tags: machine-learning

Given data points x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub> and their classifications y in the form (x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, y),

1) How do I know which points are support vectors?

2) How do I find the support vector classifier by hand including the weight and bias?

3) How do I find the margin?

The points and classifications are (0,0,1), (-1,1,1), (-1,-1,-1), (2,-2,-1) for reference.

I would not like to be given all the answers but to be shown how to work them out on my own and the intuition behind how to do so (preferably with as little abstract equations as possible). If the problem is worked out, I would appreciate if different data is used so I can work out the math for this data on my own.

Comment: For a linear SVM, draw the convex hull of each class, find which lines separate both, then maximize the margin (If the two convex regions intersect, it is harder).

Comment: I would recommend you to the following tutorial in SVM. I am sure you will get your answer. [support vector machine](http://www.svms.org/tutorials/BennettCampbell2000.pdf)